# cannot find part of path while storing image after resizing it mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, image

I am resizing image after upload to the folder.I have stored the path in db in this format
/Content/Uploads//e1f1d755-2b6c-4ec0-8b5e-0a5fa569292c.Img0001.jpg
But on resizing image i haven given the same the path i have saved it in a variable path.But it is appearing in this form C:\Content\Uploads\e1f1d755-2b6c-4ec0-8b5e-0a5fa569292c.Img0001.jpg which causing error in saving resized image.cannot find part of path
C:\Content\Uploads\e1f1d755-2b6c-4ec0-8b5e-0a5fa569292c.Img0001.jpg
Here is my code:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult UploadPic(FileManagement fmanage, HttpPostedFileBase file)
    {
        var path = String.Empty;
        var directory = "/Content/Uploads/";

        if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            String FileExtn = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(file.FileName).ToLower();
            if (!(FileExtn == ".jpg" || FileExtn == ".png" || FileExtn == ".gif"))
            {
                ViewBag.error = "Only jpg, gif and png files are allowed!";
            }

            else
            {
                var fileName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", Guid.NewGuid(), Path.GetFileName(file.FileName));
                path = Path.Combine(directory + "/", fileName);
                file.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(path));

                using (var input = new Bitmap(file.InputStream))
                {
                    int width;
                    int height;
                    if (input.Width > input.Height)
                    {
                        width = 128;
                        height = 128 * input.Height / input.Width;
                    }  //if
                    else
                    {
                        height = 128;
                        width = 128 * input.Width / input.Height;
                    }  //else
                    using (var thumb = new Bitmap(width, height))
                    using (var graphic = Graphics.FromImage(thumb))
                    {
                        graphic.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                        graphic.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                        graphic.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                        graphic.DrawImage(input, 0, 0, width, height);
                        using (var output = System.IO.File.Create(path))
                        {
                            thumb.Save(output, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                        } //using
                    } //using

                }
          }
```

How can i have the same path while storing resized image.Thanks in advance for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the following:

Instead of:

```
 var directory = "/Content/Uploads/";
```

do this:

```
 var directory = "~/Content/Uploads/";
```

Then replace:

```
path = Path.Combine(directory + "/", fileName);
```

with:

```
path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(directory), fileName);
```